# RESTEasy, CDI, embedded Jetty, bean validation is ignored

Tags: groovy, cdi, resteasy, bean-validation, embedded-jetty

I've a Groovy project where I use RESTEasy with Weld and deploy to embedded Jetty. What I can't seem to get working is bean validation. RESTEasy documentation says that adding `resteasy-validator-provider-11` along with hibernate validator dependencies (`hibernate-validator, hibernate-validator-cdi, javax.el-api, javax.el`) is enough. But the bean validation is simply ignored by RESTEasy. I curiously also get the following message in the logs:

```
plugins.validation.ValidatorContextResolver - Unable to find CDI supporting ValidatorFactory. Using default ValidatorFactory
```

Based on the suggestions on [this][1] post, I tried registering Hibernate `InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory` in META-INF/validation.xml but it depends on a BeanManager being injected and blows up at runtime.

The code can be found here https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/groovy/tree/master/movie-manager/movie-manager-web

A log gist is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8947319

I've tried everything under the sun without any success. Pls help.

Comment: It's hard to say what's the issue here without knowing the details. Generally I think you're better off using a EE container such as WildFly which integrates all these technologies for you out of the box, so you don't have to go trough this trouble yourself.

Comment: @Gunnar I'm avoiding an EE container because I want to create an executable war with the embedded container and Jetty fits the bill. I've added more details to my post. Pls help. I've tried everything under the sun without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this. Turns out, a validation.xml is not really required, `resteasy-cdi` module does a fine job of registering the BeanManager. What I was missing and not clearly documented anywhere, is that if an annotation is placed on a method, the validation engine just "decides" what should be validated. I placed a `@NotNull` on a method and it was validating the return type, not the parameters. One can use `validationAppliesTo` element in some cases but `@NotNull` doesn't have it. When I moved it from the method to the parameter, it started working.
Now I ran across what I believe is a Weld bug but I'll post that question separately.

Answer (score 1):

To do this without EE, I believe you'll need to fork the existing `InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory` but instead of using injection of the bean manager, use the CDI 1.1 class `CDI` to get a reference to the bean manager, e.g. `CDI.current().getBeanManager()`.  http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.1/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/CDI.html

You do need to be on CDI 1.1 to do this (so Weld 2+, 2.1.1 is current I believe).  Here's an example impl, based on: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/cdi/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/cdi/InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.java

```
    public class InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory implements ConstraintValidatorFactory {
        // TODO look for something with better performance (HF)
        private final Map<Object, DestructibleBeanInstance<?>> constraintValidatorMap =
                Collections.synchronizedMap( new IdentityHashMap<Object, DestructibleBeanInstance<?>>() );

        private final BeanManager beanManager;

        public InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory() {
            this.beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
            Contracts.assertNotNull( this.beanManager, "The BeanManager cannot be null" );
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> key) {
            DestructibleBeanInstance<T> destructibleBeanInstance = new DestructibleBeanInstance<T>( beanManager, key );
            constraintValidatorMap.put( destructibleBeanInstance.getInstance(), destructibleBeanInstance );
            return destructibleBeanInstance.getInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {
            DestructibleBeanInstance<?> destructibleBeanInstance = constraintValidatorMap.remove( instance );
            destructibleBeanInstance.destroy();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did that, didn't work. BeanManager is still null. Using Weld 2.1.2.Final.
`@Inject
 public InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory(BeanManager beanManager) {
     if (beanManager == null) {
         this.beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
     } 
     else {
         this.beanManager = beanManager;
     }
     
  Contracts.assertNotNull(this.beanManager, "The BeanManager cannot be null" );
  
 }`

Comment: Don't use an `@Inject` constructor, use a no arg constructor.

Comment: please see my answer above.